# Change Javascript array index

Tags: php, javascript

I have a comics website which loops through all images in a db and displays them as thumbnails.
The user can click on one of those images to see it in normal size on a viewComic.php template.

I'd like to allow users to press left and right arrows to navigate images.

So, my idea is:

1. pagination.php handles image display on correct pages (by offsetting) by looping through database result array. The user can click on a result (below) to go to that specific image on the viewcomic.php template.

   ```
   '<br />IMG: <a href="./templates/viewcomic.php?id=' . $row['imgid'] . '&image=' . $imgpath.$row['imgname'] . '">
   ```
2. Now on viewcomic.php, I get and display the image

   ```
   $imgid = $_GET['id']; 
   $imgpath = $_GET['image']; 
   <center><img src=".<?php echo  $imgpath  ?>" /></center>
   ```

The user can press left and right arrows to navigate through images...

**Question 1: Does Javascript allow you to manually set the index position in an array?**

Since I want to allow the user to get next and last images, I want them to start from the image they're currently on (the one they clicked on in pagination.php), not from the beginning of the image array. I pass along the $imgid in the URL, so I was going to set the javascript img array index == $imgid, which would allow the user to continue scrolling through the images from where they left off.

**Question 2: How can I keep the *current index* of an array?**

When I want to go a certain direction, it works fine. But if I want to change directions, I have to press the key twice. I found this is because the index is incremented after (imgIndex++) I've pressed the key. Meaning, that when it starts to go the opposite way, it first needs to decrement to return the index to the current image, and then press the key again to finally show the next image. I'm not sure how to fix this. Using ++imgIndex is also problematic because it will skip forward an image.

```
<?php
 getImages() {
//DB connection code omitted
   $img = array();
   while($row = $catResult->fetch_assoc()) {
       $img[] = "'../images/all_comics/" . $row['imgname'] . "'";
}
return $img;
?>

var imgArray = [<?php echo implode(',', getImages()) ?>];
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img = document.getElementById("theImage");
    img.src = imgArray[0];
    var imgIndex = 0;

    $(document).keydown(function (e) 
    {
        //next image
        if (e.which == 39) 
        {
            if (imgIndex == imgArray.length) 
            {
                imgIndex = 0;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[imgIndex++];
                    //now the index is ahead by 1, which is bad if you want to press <-- to get the last image because the index is ahead by 1.
        }

        //last image
        if (e.which == 37) 
        {
            if (imgIndex == 0) 
            {
                imgIndex = imgArray.length;
            }
            img.src = imgArray[--imgIndex];
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear how imgArray is initialized in your JavaScript. I suppose indices must run from 0 to [array size - 1]. If so, there is a simpe way to adjust index: `if(e.which == 39) imgIndex++; else if(e.which == 37) imgIndex--; imgIndex = (imgIndex + imgArray.length)%imgArray.length;`. I'm not sure this is about your actual problem, so I post the comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @Stan my bad, lol. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: Well, when what's the problem? You can write initial imgIndex value just from php, according to `imgid` used for `viewcomic.php` invocation (something like `var imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid; ?>;`). And as for adjusting index in a browser, I've mentioned above.

Comment: @Stan I was making a stupid mistake and not echoing out the php... so I overlooked that and thought it was something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of operations:

```
if (e.which == 39) {
    imgIndex++;            
    if (imgIndex>imgArray.length)  {
        imgIndex = 0;
    }
    img.src = imgArray[imgIndex];                
}
```

Comment: Lol thanks man. I tried a couple different ways, but kept having issues- 'ppreciate that. Do you happen to know anything about manually setting an array's index position in Javascript?

Comment: An array does not have a native "index position". You just point to any position you want using a variable.

Comment: Sorry, I knew that.. I was originally trying to set: var imgIndex = <?php echo $imgid ?>; but was having trouble using php within the javascript... just now found I wasn't echoing it- oops :/ Anyway, thanks for your help. Everything works perfectly now.